# java how to convert for loop to do while loop

Tags: java

Sorry i'm stuck on converting this to do while loop can anybody help me please.

```
int sum = 0;
int num;

System.out.print("Enter number: ");
num = sc.nextInt();
// Store the user input into variable num                               

// Complete the for loop to start from 1
// and end at num

for (int i = 1 ; i <=num ; i++)
    sum += i;

System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

and this is my do while loop

```
int sum = 0;
int num;

int i = 1;

do {
    sum += i;
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    num = sc.nextInt();
    i++;
} while (i <= num);

System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Comment: Your while loop executes `num + 1` times.

Comment: You could expect different behavior when your input is *outside* the for-loop and *inside* the while-loop.

Comment: `for` loop is checking condition first to see if it can iterate, `do-while` firsts iterates then it is checking condition if it should iterate again. If you want to have exactly same behavior you would need to add condition check before you enter `do-while`, but at this point it would mean you should simply use `while{}` loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you may notice your question has downvotes, this will explain http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks guys haha i admit this is homework i just started learning java

Comment: Hint: when learning ... seriously: try to focus on **trying** yourself. Meaning - f your program surprises you, then try to find out what is going on! By stepping through each step in a debugger; or by printing variable values; or really really insightful: by running the "program" manually on a piece of paper. Yes, that takes **effort**, but you learn much more from it than from asking other people to explain such basic stuff to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
    int num;
    int i = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    num = sc.nextInt();
    do{
    sum += i;
    i++;
    }
    while ( i <=num );

    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Initialize i to zero, since do-while does first before checking, as opposed to for that checks first before doing. And your do-while will work the same as your for.Or else your do-while will have a sum of 1 even if your num is 0. As opposed to your for that will have sum=0 if num is 0.

Comment: why put System.out.print("Enter number: "); and num = sc.nextInt(); ouside of loop

Comment: because you need that variable only once unless you are adding it to sum

Comment: @stevenTan Hint: you are also having it outside of `for` loop in your original code. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you enter num value outside the for, the second case you do it on the do/while. So I supposed you want to do this:

```
//Variables
int sum = 0;
int num;
int i = 0;

//Select num
System.out.print("Enter number: ");
num = sc.nextInt();

do {
    sum += i;
    i++;
} while (i <=num);

System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you may have to study the basics of the loops a bit more. The difference between while loop and do-while loop is the place where the condition is being checked. Do-while loop checks the condition after executing the code block. And the while loop doesn't. It checks before the execution.

```
int num = sc.nextInt();
int i = 1;
int sum = 0;
do{
    sum += i;
        i++;
}while(i <= num);       //check condition after the running do block
System.out.println(sum);
```

**This depends on your input. That means if your input is zero the answer will be wrong. Because your i = 1 and sum becomes equals to 1.